# Fatal exception preventing flashing ESP8266 ESP-01

Tags: esp8266, flash

My issue arose when attempting to flash several of my ESP8266 ESP-01 module (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33010444450.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dNkKYQZ). In the past and with the first chip I got it working just fine with the loader from the Espressif website, but the second and third proved to be stubborn.

**The problem:**

The issue I am struggling with is that during flashing the software does not recognize/synchronize with the chip. When attempting to do this, the indicator blue-led on the chip is constantly on. When checking the communication with the chip in normal mode (at Baud 15200) the chip responds normally to AT commands and presents version number etc. When in flash mode, however, the chip responds at Baud 74880 by flooding TX with

```
Fatal exception (0): 
epc1=0x400fffa8, epc2=0x00000000, epc3=0x00000000, excvaddr=0x00000000, depc=0x00000000
```

From research, I gathered that this could be a faulty flash in the past causing a wrong configuration in flash mode but I still haven't found a solution to this problem as the chip does not respond when attempting to re-flash.

**The setup**

As a setup, I have both an Arduino Uno with the chip removed(https://www.instructables.com/Flash-or-Upgrade-Firmware-on-ESP8266-ESP-01-Module/) as well as an ESP-dongle(https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32693314450.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.506e4c4ddAqtwB) with a switch soldered on between GND and GPIO0. Furthermore:

- Vin -> 3.3V
- CH_EN -> 3.3V
- Tx -> Tx
- Rx -> Rx
- GPIO_0 -> GND
- GND -> GND

As software, I tried that from the Espressif website (latest version and that of Jan 2021) as well as NodeMCU Firmware Programmer. Again, the first chip responded after a while (also not ideal), but the second and others fail to do so.

**The question**

My question is thus what could be causing this problem, what I can do to rectify the issue, and finally what the most secure way to flash such chips is as my previous one clearly did not work.

Thanks for any tips in advance,

Cheers

Comment: try to pull-up io 2

Comment: Try using a lower baud rate. Maybe 57600. I have found that some chips that are difficult to program at 115200 will reliably program at a slightly lower baud rate.